# Bash - catch the output of a command

Tags: bash

I am trying to check the output of a command and run different commands depending on the output.

```
count="1"
for f in "$@"; do
   BASE=${f%.*}
#    if [ -e "${BASE}_${suffix}_${suffix2}.mp4" ]; then
    echo -e "Reading GPS metadata using MediaInfo file ${count}/${#@} "$(basename "${BASE}_${suffix}_${suffix2}.mp4")"
   mediainfo "${BASE}_${suffix}_${suffix2}.mp4" | grep "©xyz" | head -n 1
    if [[ $? != *xyz* ]]; then
    echo -e "WARNING!!! No GPS information found! File ${count}/${#@} "$(basename "${BASE}_${suffix}_${suffix2}.mp4")" || exit 1
    fi
    ((count++))
done
```

MediaInfo is the command I am checking the output of.
If a video file has "©xyz" atom written into it the output looks like this:

```
$ mediainfo FILE | grep "©xyz" | head -n 1
$ ©xyz                                     : +60.9613-125.9309/
$
```

otherwise it is null

```
$ mediainfo FILE | grep "©xyz" | head -n 1
$
```

The above code does not work and echos the warning even when ©xyz presented.
Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using the capture the output of the `mediainfo` command is plain wrong. When using `grep` you can use its return code (the output of `$?`) directly in the if-conditional

```
if mediainfo "${BASE}_${suffix}_${suffix2}.mp4" | grep -q "©xyz" 2> /dev/null; 
then
..
```

The `-q` flag in `grep` instructs it to run the command silently without throwing any results to `stdout`, and the part `2>/dev/null` suppresses any errors thrown via `stderr`, so you will get the if-conditional *pass* when the string is present and `fail` if not present

Answer (score 0):

`$?` is the exit code of the command: a number between 0 and 255. It's not related to stdout, where your value "xyz" is written.

To match in stdout, you can just use `grep`:

```
if mediainfo "${BASE}_${suffix}_${suffix2}.mp4" | grep -q "©xyz"
then
  echo "It contained that thing"
else
  echo "It did not"
fi
```